# Offline app data

Tags: ios, swift

which is the best way to store data in an offline ios app? For example if i want to wright contacts app which will have persons name and it's corresponding data like mobile number, address, etc. I want to know how to store all that data. Thanks.

Comment: If your data is less(username , passwords...), then you can use NSUserDefaults. If you have huge amount of data, then use Core Data or sqlite.

Comment: thanks for response. The data is huge and the app is offline only. So can you advise one out of these three options?

Comment: You can use Core Data.